# What is the correct way to access a large amount of data that is private to a class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++98

I'm just wondering how to resolve this with C98 (so no `shared_ptr`):

- I have a really big class with a lot of data (`BigData`)
- I have a class `DataStorage` that keeps track of that data in a `map`
- The data is unlikely to change, but can
- I'm in a multithreading environment

  ```
   class BigData;

   class DataStorage{
    public:
         const BigData *getStuff(int which_one) const{
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(mut);     
             return &myReallyBigDatas[which_one]; // thanks Donghui
         }
    protected:
       mutable mutex mut;
       map<int,BigData> myReallyBigDatas;
   }
  ```

(as suggested by Keith M. I haven't mentioned the problem that I try to solve)

I know that this code is wrong and, from my point of view, I want to resolve two major problems:

1. If the object returned desapear because this position on map are delete or overwritten (I will have a pointer pointing to no where, UB!)
2. If the instance of BigData returned is modified

Of course, I want to find a solution that avoid future mistakes from other people changing this code

I came up with these solutions:

1. Include a mutex to BigData. This solve problem 2
2. Change the function to return a real object, not a pointer (this is very nice, but has the drawback of killing performance while it's making a copy of a really big class) This solve both problems
3. Implement my own shared_ptr class (can't use C11 nor boost). This solve problem 1
4. Create a lock / unlock on class DataStorage (really awful!). This solve both problems
5. Keep wrong and pray a lot. This....

I'm pretty sure that a lot of people have found a piece of code like this in legacy code, and I would like to find the best solution.

P.S. I know that I'm using a C11 mutex. My real code does not have it, but it's easier to write the example code this way.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What's the problem with this code that you're having? Data getting deleted or changing while being fetched? Or just bad performance? Or it just gives you compiler warnings? You've got two answers already but they're both totally different because you didn't really ask a concrete question.

Comment: @KeithM thanks for you comment, I agree with you that I don't say exactly what I need to solve. I have edit muy question trying to clarify this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `shared_ptr` and `mutex` are quite independent from each other, and you might need both - `shared_ptr` is used to guarantee exactly one resource release, while `mutex` is used to guarantee no concurrent read/write operations (or concurrent reads as well, depends on type of mutex).

Using `shared_ptr` means basically that there is no single owner of the data. While this is possible to manage (e.g. reference counting), it's not always the best solution (remember about circular dependencies, need for `weak_ptr` etc.) - sometimes it's better to find out a single owner of the resource who will be responsible for deallocating it when it's no longer necessary (e.g. if you have a pool of worker threads, it may be the one that spawns the others) - of course, then you have to guarantee that it'll live longer than the others, to make the data accessible for everyone. So you have several options for managing lifetime of the object:

- "borrow" the code from boost/C++11 standard library/Loki/some-other-existing-implementation (check out licenses to verify if you can use them) without using whole library - you'll probably need to make changes to them
- write your own smart pointer - hard and only for pros- totally not recommended
- select a single owner of the resource - which is what I'd recommend

When it comes to access conflict management, there are basically two approaches:

- manage them using some kind of lock (I assume you have one available)
- avoid them by allowing only a single thread to write to the object. Other ones which might normally want to will have to request a write from the "owner thread". This approach fits goes pretty well with single owner of resource, but it's more of an actor model than typical, shared-memory multithreading, so may be hard to introduce in a legacy application.

You can use lock with any of the tree memory management methods, the single-writer approach goes best with single-owner. Note that this is a significant change of paradigm an might require a lot of work implementing things like message queues and workers.

If you already have the infrastructure (queues, workers etc.) I'd recommend looking at single-owner, single-writer approach, otherwise single-owner with locks may be a good solution. If you're unable to select a single owner, extract code from existing libraries - don't write it yourself, because you'll make some mistakes, and memory management in multithreaded environment is *really* hard

*EDIT 1*

Now that you've clarified the question, I feel that the answer is a bit too high-level, so I'll add some more details.

The simplest thing you can do is to return a `BigData&` instead of `BigData*` - nobody should remove it then (of course it's possible, but virtually everything is in C++). Otherwise, you can also:

- allow only a single thread to use single `BigData` instance - (for example by storing additional `std::map<int, thread_id>` with info about used `BigData` - only if you don't require concurrent access to the same instance from multiple threads
- return something like `BigDataProxy` instead of `BigData` - the `Proxy` should have a special function for resource removal, which would be then executed by the "last one interested" - this is really just a special case of `shared_ptr`, but may be simpler to implement.

Conceptually the `Proxy` thing would be something like (pseudocode - ignoring private/public members etc.):

```
class BigDataProxy {
  public:
  BigDataProxy(data_, instanceId_): data(data_), instanceId(instanceId_) {
    std::lock_guard l(data.mutex);
    data.interestedThreads[instanceId].insert(this_thread::thread_id);
  }

  ~BigDataProxy() {
    std::lock_guard l(data.mutex);
    data.interestedThreads[instanceId].remove(this_thread::thread_id)
    if(data.interestedThreads[instanceId].empty() && data.toDelete.contains(instanceId) {
      data.elems.remove(instanceId);
      data.toDelete.remove(instanceId);
    }
  }

  BigData& operator*() {
    return data.elems[instanceId];
  }
  void remove() {
     std::lock_guard l(data.mutex);
     data.toDelete.add(instanceId);
  }

  private: 
    DataStorage& data;
    int instanceId;
}
```

with changes in `DataStorage` requiring it to look like this:

```
class DataStorage {

  std::mutex mutex;
  std::map<int, BigData> elems;
  std::set<int> toDelete;
  std::map<int, std::set<thread_id> > interested_threads;
}
```

Note that this is pseudocode and exception handling will be tough here.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. About managing lifetime, I guess that who made this code choose _"select a single owner of the resource"_ but I cant figure out how to garantee that. If some other class have a pointer to my internal data how I can't trace lifetime of this pointer without smartpointer? (I'm pretty sure that you have already answer that in your post, but, please, clarify this point).

Comment: Some questions: If I return `BigData&` is not possible that somebody set another instance in my map and this reference is pointing nowhere?. And another one, the control of access by thread I don't known how to achieve it. Do you mean that I return a NULL is a thread is already accessing this element?

Comment: 1.) It is theoretically possible by doing something like `const_cast<void*>(&myData) = nullptr;`, but that's quite unreasonable to write. When you return a reference it's clear that you don't hand out the ownership of the object (it's not clear when you return a pointer). 2.) It really depends on your case - you can return `nullptr`, throw an exception, lock on a mutex during request or during first usage - all these are valid solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!, now I have a better ways to imprive this code!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct: keep data private, and provide a getter to get the data or part of the data.

Your code has a mistake in it. The signature of getStuff() returns a pointer to BigData, but the implementation returns a reference to BigData. Type mismatch.

You are right in that you don't want to make copies of BigData. So you have three choices:

- return myReallyBigDatas[which_one];  // return BigData&
- return &myReallyBigData[which_one];  // return BigData*
- return myReallyBigDatas.find(which_one);  // return map::iterator

Comment: Can you explain your last return? returning a iterator looks like a very bad solution

Comment: The last return is to return a map::iterator. What makes you think returning an iterator is a very bad solution?